# Cell array assignment result returns to ans `object` instead of expected object `obj`

Tags: matlab, oop, cell-array

I had trouble while deciding the title which should be simple and expressive enough. If you can simplify the title, please go ahead and edit it.

---

I have a `Model`class in which I have a method for adding a `node.flow.Pipe` object into `Model`'s `nodeArray` (which is a cell array).

```
classdef Model

    properties

        nodeArray = {} 

    end

    ...        

    methods

        function result = Model()

        end

        function obj = addNode(obj, node)
            size = numel(obj.nodeArray);
            obj.nodeArray{size+1} = node;
        end

    ...
    end        
end
```

When I create a `Model` object and `node.flow.Pipe` object and then use `Model`'s `addNode(node)` method, instead of adding a node to that object, Matlab creates a new object `ans`.

```
>> newModel = Model

newModel = 

  Model with properties:

                       nodeArray: {}
                   numberOfNodes: 0
                   stateVariable: []
          numberOfStateVariables: 0
            steadyStateEquations: []
    numberOfSteadyStateEquations: 0

>> newModel.addNode(node.flow.Pipe)

ans = 

  Model with properties:

        nodeArray: {[1×1 node.flow.Pipe]}
    numberOfNodes: 1

>> newModel.nodeArray

ans =

  0×0 empty cell array
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, all classes in MATLAB are [value classes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/fundamental-matlab-classes.html) and are copied (by value) whenever you perform an assignment. In order to access classes my reference, you need to inherit from MATLAB's built-in `handle` class.

```
classdef Model < handle
```

There is an extensive description of the difference between handle and value classes in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html).